# rxjs takeuntil, check until observable source is valid

Tags: rxjs

After searching for hours... most of example is like this...

```
var source = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000)
    .takeUntil(Rx.Observable.timer(5000));

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) { console.log('Next: ' + x); },
    function (err) { console.log('Error: ' + err); },
    function () { console.log('Completed'); })
```

Result

```
Next: 0
Next: 1
Next: 2
Next: 3
Next: 4
Completed
```

but, I wan to know is it possible to check from source value not another observable object.. something like this..

```
var source = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000)
    .takeUntil((result) => result == 5);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is [takeWhile](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeWhile)

```
var source = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000)
    .takeWhile((result) => result < 5);

source.subscribe(
    (val) => console.log(val),
    (err) => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('complete')
);
```

Comment: hi, if I wanna until other outside value is valid, how do I make it? thx

Comment: I guess you can put it inside ```(result) => result < 5 && otherValue``` but that want be functional. proper way would be something like Observable.combineLatest(Observable.of(otherValue), Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000)).takeWhile(([result1, result2]) => doSomethingWitResulst);